# rails way to transfer polymorphic object through url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

how do i pass a polymorphic object to another controller?

for example redirecting from messages/1/

to requests/new?object_type=message&object_id=1

or, second example, from files/154/

to requests/new?object_type=file&object_id=154

is

```
redirect_to new_request_path(:object_type => params[:controller].classify, :object_id => params[:id])
```

right?

Request model has

```
  belongs_to      :object , :polymorphic => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nest your routes, for example:

```
messages/1/requests/new
files/154/requests/new

redirect_to new_comments_request_path(Comment.find(1))
```

[routes guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: thanks for information on nested routes. in my case, all polymorphic objects, like Message,File,Comment etc get redirected in the same method. is there any way to use something like "new_request_path(@polymorphicobject)" instead of  "new_comments_request_path", "new_messages_request_path" etc separately?

Comment: you can use http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources, if you use it there is a url helper "new_resource_url"- I think it's what you look for.